# Installing LaTeX package

Tags: linux, installation, latex, packages

I am trying to install the amsmath package for LaTeX on Linux Mint 16.  I am using the `tlmgr amsmath` or `sudo tlmgr amsmath` commands, but both of them are giving me this error:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: unknown action: amsmath; try --help if you need it.
```

I have also tried `tlmgr install amsmath` and `sudo tlmgr install amsmath`, but they are giving me:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/evorlor/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5308.
```

Any ideas on a fix?  My ultimate goal is to line up an equation by the = signs, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You have not initialized *tlmgr*. Try first

```
 tlmgr init-usertree
```

and then

```
 tlmgr install amsmath
```

If this does not work, it is not your fault, but you will have to be patient: see posts n.3 and 4 in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/1242914), and you will have to wait for a fix. In my Debian unstable, I do not experience such a bug, and tlmgr works perfectly.

Comment: Uh oh. Same error.  (running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/evorlor/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5308.